# Убрать обязательное заполнение email у комментария

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, как убрать обязательное заполнение email в комментариях WP?
Имя по-прежнему должно оставаться обязательным для заполнения. Как я понял они связаны одной функцией.

Пробовал вот так:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'filter_function_name_3090' );
    function filter_function_name_3090( $fields ){
    unset( $fields['email'] );

    $fields['email'] = '<p class="comment-form-email">' .
   '<label for="email">' . __( 'Email' ) . '</label>' .
   '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" size="30"/></p>';

return $fields;
}
```

После такого email отображается как необязательное, но все равно требует заполнения.

Comment: Снимите в админке галку "Требовать от пользователя имя и email для комментирования". Примерно так называется.

Comment: Это я пробовал, но тогда и имя становится не обязательным

Comment: Сделайте с ним ровно то же самое, что вы делаете с email, только в код вывода input добавьте required

Comment: И да, строчка с unset в вашем коде лишняя